# Auto-Connectivity with Bluetooth Device to Android Phone

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am using a Bluetooth device to connect with the android Phone manually there is no problem. But My Question is how can I connect automatically when I starts my Activity or Application .
I am taking the reference of Bluetooth chat in Sample API to connect. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Please Suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this using Bluetooth API. First of all you need to get that Device's Address. Now in activity you need to make it hardcode(static) for connection. you can write code in OnCreate() Method of Activity for Automatic Connection.

Comment: Yes i Did it and it connect successfully with device but it lost its connection within 2-5 sec

Comment: well after doing connection you need to do some activity like sending. or you need to put that code in a repetative task like loop or TimerTask. so your connection will be never loss.

Comment: hey Please put it accept, so that it can be useful for others :)

Comment: After connecting i m reading a data from device and draw graph . so how could they lost its connection if devices are within the range.

Answer (score 0):

By the default API example, I get the same problem :
when connecting each other more 5 seconds, it will lost automatically
However, finally, I found that I put a finish() in the onCreate() method for debugging. when I take it off, it works fine all the time that sending data to the bluetooth chat demo.

it does not require discovery. and if will pair up the first time, and next time, it will just send directly

the most important code as following:

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getRemoteDevice("6C:83:36:A0:0E:89");

    new ConnectThread(device).start();
```

ConnectThread can be found in the Android Demo API:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html